# Can a capacitor be charged with multiple batteries connected in series

Tags: capacitance, batteries

I connect 2 9-volt batteries in series. Then I connect that to a capacitor. Will that then charge the capacitor to 18 volts?

Comment: Well, do you have any particular reason to think that it doesn't?

Comment: Depending on the size of the capacitor you may want to add a resistor to limit the charging current and protect the batteries from overheating or worse. When I charge my 2x3500F ultra capacitors with a current of 5A (not from batteries of course) for 30 minutes, I use heatsinks and cooling fans so the current limiting resistors would not catch fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Of course only if the connection between the two voltage sources (batteries) is between opposite polarities (positive terminal of one battery connected to negative terminal of the other battery) so that the voltages add.